# Webview on desktop site "https://www.facebook.com/messages" not working or cant see messages on webview on desktop site

Tags: java, android, webview

I have tried to use facebok on webview and set mode to desktop site webview opened on facebook on desktop site but cant open the menu messages notifications window how can i solve these

```
    webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview1.getSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
     webview1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  webview1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview1.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
```